# multiple onmouseover events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of rollovers that display numbers above the bullets as you roll over them. I want the numbers to disappear onmouseout but remain on onmousedown until the next onmousedown. Is there an easier way of doing this than giving each number its own id and toggling it on and off? I hope this makes sense?!?12

Thanks!

CSS

```
#numbers1, #numbers2, #numbers3, #numbers4 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 9px;
color: #6e6965;
margin: -10px 0 0 2px;
position: absolute;
display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<span onmouseover="document.rollimg.src=image1.src; document.getElementById('numbers1').style.display = 'inline';">
<a class="bullet"><div id="numbers1">1</div></a></span>

<span onmouseover="document.rollimg.src=image2.src; document.getElementById('numbers2').style.display = 'inline';" 
<a class="bullet"><div id="numbers2">2</div></a></span>

<span onmouseover="document.rollimg.src=image3.src; document.getElementById('numbers3').style.display = 'inline';" 
<a class="bullet"><div id="numbers3">3</div></a></span>

<span onmouseover="document.rollimg.src=image4.src; document.getElementById('numbers4').style.display = 'inline';" 
<a class="bullet"><div id="numbers4">4</div></a></span>
```

Comment: You want the previously-hovered element's number to remain until another element is hovered-over? Oh, and your HTML seems to be invalid, multiple closing `</a>` tags, a `div` nested within an `a`, itself within a `span`.

Comment: You might look into abstracting this out to a function which attaches it programmatically.  Makes it a little clearer when you're trying to do this stuff since you can use the event object more abstractly (which should contain references to the element you've left and the one you're entering)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my multiple closing david, must have happened as I copied and pasted it over. Fixed now. I'm guessing that a 'div' within an 'a' with a 'span' is bad? I can't see another way I could do it? @tkone - thanks for your response, I'll look into it, not sure where to start though!

Comment: [This might give you some help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: Thanks, looking into it, appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'div' within an 'a' with a 'span' is legal as of HTML5.  It doesn't make much sense without CSS, though.

Comment: I think this can be done with CSS alone.  Is this approximately what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/FpSgW/1/

Comment: So with HTML5 you can put block elements into anchors, so `<a><div></div></a>` is fine. But you are not allowed to put a block element into a `<span>`-Tag like this: `<span><div></div></span>` or `<span><article></article></span>` even if you put an `<a>` between the block element and the `span`, it wouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with CSS `:hover` and `:focus` - no JavaScript needed.

```
a div {
    display:none;
}

a:hover div, a:focus div {
    display: block;
}

a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

For the `:focus` selector to work properly, you'll also need a `tabindex` on each `a` element; I suggest `tabindex="-1"` (that's an HTML attribute).  Of course, you'll also need to restrict this to specific `a` elements, rather than all links on the page.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4yq5/

jsFiddle based on the code from the question: http://jsfiddle.net/FpSgW/1/

Comment: @dave: I notice that you didn't provide us with the image elements, so I didn't include them in my answer.  They should be able to follow approximately the same logic as the divs, though.

Comment: Fantastic, worked a treat - than you so much, must have spent hours on this! Just need need to have the first bullet 'active' when the page loads. '#numbers a:active div' isn't working - any ideas why?

Comment: `:active` targets something that the user is partway through clicking (mouse button is still down) - probably not what you want.  You could call `focus()` (JavaScript) on the first bullet when the page loads, but remember that only one thing on the entire page can be focused at a time.  If you can't accept the selected bullet being deselected whenever the user clicks elsewhere on the page, then you'll have to go with a JavaScript method, as in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FpSgW/3/

Comment: Thanks Brilliand, really appreciate your help!